# Using instanceof operarator for deserialization

Tags: java, instanceof

I have come across different posts which says that using instanceof is not considered a good practice.

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31
https://www.artima.com/interfacedesign/PreferPoly.html

I am in a situation where I have a serialized object which can be of 7,8 actual types. Right now I am using `insntanceof` operator and checking with various if conditions whether the object is of actual type and then do some operations.

is my design bad?

If so how do I solve this issue without using `instanceof`?

The inheritance hierarchy is different for each object so that makes it hard for me to replace it with polymorphism.

code

```
 public String exportAsPMML(MLModel model) throws MLModelHandlerException {
        Externalizable extModel = model.getModel();

        //Deserializing to find the actual type of the model
        if (extModel instanceof MLClassificationModel) {
            ClassificationModel clasModel = ((MLClassificationModel) extModel).getModel();
            if (clasModel instanceof LogisticRegressionModel) {
                return ((LogisticRegressionModel) clasModel).toPMML();
            } else {
                throw new MLModelHandlerException("PMML export not supported for model type");
            }
        } else if (extModel instanceof MLGeneralizedLinearModel) {
            GeneralizedLinearModel genModel = ((MLGeneralizedLinearModel) extModel).getModel();
            if (genModel instanceof LinearRegressionModel) {
                return ((LinearRegressionModel) genModel).toPMML();
            } else if (genModel instanceof LassoModel) {
                return ((LassoModel) genModel).toPMML();
            } else if (genModel instanceof RidgeRegressionModel) {
                return ((RidgeRegressionModel) genModel).toPMML();
            } else {
                throw new MLModelHandlerException("PMML export not supported for model type");
            }
        } else if (extModel instanceof MLKMeansModel) {
            KMeansModel kmeansModel = ((MLKMeansModel) extModel).getModel();
            return kmeansModel.toPMML();
        } else {
            throw new MLModelHandlerException("PMML export not supported for model type");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code where you have used `instanceof` ?

Comment: You could store the type as a member

Comment: Its hard to get a clear picture without actual code. But depending on your design, instanceof might be a valid solution. You could also design with generics

Comment: I Have added the code

Comment: This screams for a base clase/common interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the existing interface [`PMMLExportable`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/pmml/PMMLExportable.html)

```
GeneralizedLinearModel genModel = ((MLGeneralizedLinearModel) extModel).getModel();
if (genModel instanceof PMMLExportable) {
    return ((PMMLExportable) genModel).toPMML();
} else {
    throw new MLModelHandlerException("PMML export not supported for model type");
}
```

Then add your own interface to get this:

```
public interface PpmlModelContainer{
    PMMLExportable getPMMLExportable();
}

 public String exportAsPMML(MLModel model) throws MLModelHandlerException {
    Externalizable extModel = model.getModel();

    if (extModel instanceof PpmlModelContainer) {
        PMMLExportable ppmlModel = ((PpmlModelContainer) extModel).getPMMLExportable();
        return ppmlModel.toPMML();
    } else {
        throw new MLModelHandlerException("PMML export not supported for model type");
    }
}
```

What needs to implement what:

```
MLClassificationModel implements PpmlModelContainer
MLGeneralizedLinearModel implements PpmlModelContainer
MLKMeansModel implements PpmlModelContainer
```

The system is now [open closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). Open to extension, closed to modification.

Comment: but kmeansModel and LogisticRegressionModel does not extend GeneralizedLinearModel

Comment: OK, I've added an interface option and extended it to your whole problem.

Comment: The problem is LogisticRegressionModel, LinearRegressionModel etc are from spark MLlib and I have to implement this without modifying the spark internals

Comment: There's already an interface to use: [`PMMLExportable`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/pmml/PMMLExportable.html)!

Answer (score 1):

Though using `instanceof` is assumed to be a code smell, this is not the case always. In cases when you definitely needs to know the type of an object before doing anything then `instanceof` is a good option.

But having lots and lots of them and invoking separate methods based on type (using casting) is not a good option. In that case we need to reconsider the hierarchy and possible refactoring.

In your case it seems you can have a base interface having method `toPMML` which can be implemented by all concrete classes. This is actually what we mean by `Program to interface`.